# Using IsValueCreated before accessing LazyLoadObject.Value

Tags: c#, lazy-loading

I'm working with some C# code that's using .Net 4 Lazy loads and I'm not super familiar with it. I'm trying to figure out if this particular code is useless or not.

Originally the property and code below where in the same class, but now I've moved the code to an external class that no longer has access to the private "lazyRecords" property. I'm wondering what the point of checking "lazyRecords.IsValueCreated" is since the lazyRecords.Value has not been invoked yet, wouldn't it always be false? Or is it checking to see if another thread somehow invoked the Value? Or is it doing this in case of a thread exception that resulted in not loading the object?

Property:

```
private Lazy<List<Record>> lazyRecords;
public List<Record> Records
{
    get
    {
        return lazyRecords.Value;
    }
    set
    {
        lazyRecords = new Lazy<List<Record>>(() => value);
    }
}
```

Code:

```
public Category LoadCategory(BaseClient client)
{
    Category category = new Category();
    category.Records = client.RecordClient.GetRecordsByCategoryID(category.ID);

    if (lazyRecords.IsValueCreated)
    {
        category.WorldRecord = category.Records.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
       category.WorldRecord = client.RecordClient.GetWorldRecord(category.ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your property gives nothing for lazy computation because you can set only already created value (new lazy object is the redundant wrapping of an already created object)

Comment: Also `category.Records = new Lazy<List<Record>>` looks like uncompilable, Records has List<Record> type, not lazy.

Comment: Correct sorry I glommed the code and messed that up, let me edit the post. So are you saying the check for “IsValueCreated” is useless here, because I think so as well. Testing I see that bool only goes to true once the lazyRecords.Value is envoked, so it woulda always be false in this statement as it has not yet been envoked right?

Comment: Regarding setting an already created value, I’m setting the value to a lazy private property so the value should not have been created on the Set, right? The value should only be created on the Get.

Comment: Even with your edit, the code still looks borked. What possible reason could there be to use `Lazy<T>`, when the object is going to be initialized as `lazyRecords = new Lazy<List<Record>>(() => value);`? The point of lazy init is to defer expensive processing until you know you'll need it. If all your lazy init does is return an **already-computed value**, you aren't saving anything. Your question is primarily opinion based, but I'd say my opinion is that almost every line of code you posted is just plain wrong. I cannot imagine any context you could add that would change my opinion of that.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I understand now why this code won't work. The original code was doing something similar to Daniel's answer below, it was setting the private internal Lazy propery to an lazy object, so no value had yet been created. Then the property was only a get and returning lazyRecords.Value. So with that implimentation it was using lazy correctly. Ideally I'd like to set the property to the lazy and somehow return the lazy.value, but it looks like that might not be possible. I might make 2 public properties, one for the lazy and the other a readonly of lazy.value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is pretty useless, yes. To help you understand why, consider this very minimal version of `Lazy` (the real class has more options and logic to take care of multiple threads, but this is the rough idea):

```
public class Lazy<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> _creator;
    private T _cachedValue;

    public Lazy(Func<T> creator) => _creator = creator;

    public bool IsValueCreated { get; private set; }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!IsValueCreated)
            {
                _cachedValue = _creator();
                IsValueCreated = true;
            }

            return _cachedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

The delegate passed to the constructor is called on demand, the first time the `Value` is requested. In the code you've posted there is no point to this because the delegate simply returns the `value` passed into the setter.

As to the `LoadCategory` method, the code you posted is hard to decipher. It directly accesses `lazyRecords`, implying it's a method of the same class. But then it accesses `Records` on a different object.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, yea it looks like I got the implementation of lazy wrong when i was editing this code. I thought I could have the setter be lazy on the property and then return the value in the get. The original code was behaving correctly because it was setting a private lazy variable, then the property was read only and returned lazy.value. So I'm going to hunt around to see if there's some cool way of doing that all in one property, but its looking like I'll need to make 2 properties, one for setting the lazy object and the other ready only returning lazy.value.

Comment: @mgmedick it may help if you think of `Lazy` as a way of delaying the creation of an object until it is requested. That way if it is never requested then you never need to create it. If you have some code that is explicitly setting the full object, then `Lazy` serves no purpose for you. But for example, if the setting accepted an ID, and then the `Lazy`'s creator function would use that ID to retrieve something from an external service (costly) then that might make more sense.

Comment: Makes sense, so the technique I'm going with now is "public Lazy<List<Record>> recordsLazy {get; set;}". Then "public List<Record> Records { get { return recordsLazy.Value } };". This way I can set the lazy property and still have it not created until the Records property is accessed. It would be nice if there was a way to cook that behavior into a single property but I think this implementation is ok. Thanks for the help.